# Python Bottle Framework Loading Old Code (Despite Cache Clearing)

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, caching, bottle

Have successfully worked Bottle for four hours, returning code/text by calling various URLs.

For the past hour, everything is now re-routing to an old error route I set up.  With nothing else in the file:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello"

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

is returning:

```
Nothing here. Redirecting you to the login page!
```

Have:
- closed IDLE & the .py file
- deleted the bottle.pyc that's in the project directory
- cleared all browser data, both Firefox & Chrome, multiple times
- copied the .py file (to the same directory) & run IDLE from there

Any ideas why it's loading details I deleted an hour ago?

Regards

Comment: I have seen problems like this when there are python processes running in the background using old code. Check for any relevant python processes and shut them down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, some more things to try:

1. Make sure you've really (really) shut down the process.  Try requesting the page after you've exited your program; your client (browser) should get a "connection refused."
2. Delete all `.pyc` files.  (In particular, you should delete your own--`bottle.pyc` isn't the problem.)
3. Test your web service with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), not with a browser.  This way you can absolutely eliminate the browser cache as a culprit.

That's it for off-the-top-of-my-head.  If I think of more, I'll come back and add to the list.  Good luck!